# How to manage free and paid app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I currently have a live paid Android app with a few customers. I'm planning on releasing a free version, but there are a few problems I have:

1. I considered converting paid app to free with in-app payments to unlock full version, but I need a way to know which users already paid for the app before I converted it to freemium - Google Checkout only gives order ID, not phone's IMEI or anything that identify the purchase, so that they won't have to buy it again to unlock full features.
2. Second option is to create another project, free version of the paid app. But it's an ugly solution I think - I'd have to update two almost the same codebases? Or could it be avoided/automated somehow? Is there any tool in Eclipse to write a script that will help me generate free version?

Comment: For option 2, [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) is the official solution

Answer (score 0):

1. You can post a flag in SharedPreferences which determines if the apps was paid within MODE_PRIVATE. But be aware: rooted phones can modify them.
2. I dont think there is a tool for that just copy the paid and refactor->rename the package. This is not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

For (2) - here is what you have to do:

1. Change your current project into an Android Library project.
2. Create two new projects: XXXPaid and XXXFree that have different package ids (com.x.y) in their AndroidManifest. Both should use your Android Library project created in (1) above. Keep the current paid app package name if you want to update it.
3. You're done. Upload the both apps to the Google Play store, one for $, the other free.

No need to copy any code.
Even better - you can override any resource or code in the new projects to put differences between the two products you have created.